# Query to find increase over time period

Tags: postgresql

I have a `stats_by_dates` table which contains a score that's measured every day for a song. How do I find the songs that have the highest increase in score?

The columns in this table are: `id`, `song_id`, `date`, `score`.

This is what I have so far but it's not quiet right:

```
select song_id, date, score - coalesce(lag(score) over (partition by song_id order by date desc), 0) as delta
from stats_by_dates
group by song_id, date, score
order by score desc limit 100
```

This is returning the top 100 songs by score instead of the top 100 songs with the highest increase in score. Once I get that working, I also want to apply the query to find the fastest rising song in past 3 days. Thank you!

Comment: To make it clear, please provide an example table data an expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you need to get the first score and the last score for a song and calculate the difference (delta), which will represent how the score changed over time.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    song_id, 
    -- the first score of a song
    first_value(score) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id ORDER BY date ASC) as first_score, 
    -- the last score of a song
    first_value(score) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id ORDER BY date DESC) as last_score,
    -- the difference (delta) between the first and the last scores
    (first_value(score) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id ORDER BY date DESC) - first_value(score) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id ORDER BY date ASC)) as delta
FROM stats_by_dates
WHERE date > now() - INTERVAL '3 day' -- get score for the last 3 days
ORDER BY delta DESC LIMIT 100
```